# Writing Array to txt file with requested name

Tags: python, arrays, file-io

I'm fairly new to Python and I'm fairly new to working with file I/O. I'm having trouble coming up with how to write an array to a new txt file whose name is entered by the user. Below is the code I have written:

```
def main():
    # Opens file
    fh = open("A5Nums.txt", "r")
    array = [ ]
    # Reads numbers into an array
    for line in fh.readlines():
        for i in line.split():
            array.append(int(i))
    # Prints the array
    print (array)

    # Reverses the array
    array.reverse()

    # Prints the reversed array
    print (array)

    # Closes the input file
    fh.close()    

main()
```

After reversing the array, I need to request a name for the output file from the user and then save the file according to what they entered. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the filename from the user in Python 3.x

```
outfile = input("Please name your output file")
```

Or Python 2.x

```
outfile = raw_input("Please name your output file")
```

Then write like this

```
with open(outfile, "w+") as fOut:
    strArray = list(map(str, array))
    fOut.writelines(strArray)
```

Comment: Would I need to put this within main?

Comment: Yes, after `fh.close()` you can put these next few lines in.

Comment: You can use `map` to convert the list of `int` to a list of `str`. See my edit.